# How to accept D&D for div, but propagate clicks?

Tags: html, css, node.js

I have a windows full-sized `div` container which reacts to incoming drag&drop events for files.

```html
<div id="drag-overlay">
  <div id="drag-overlay-text">This is shown while drag is active...</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the container doesn't propagate clicks to underlying objects like buttons anymore. Is there a simple **CSS** fix, or do I need to register a click-handler on the div container and manually propagate the clicks/drags manually? Latter doesn't really feel like a good solution

```css
#drag-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Registration of the drag and drop handler:

```js
var holder = document.getElementById('drag-overlay');
holder.ondragover = () => { ...
holder.ondragleave = () => { ...
holder.ondragend = () => { ...
holder.ondrop = (e: DragEvent) => { ...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the problem is the buttons are technically "under" the `drag-overlay` since its absolutely positioned, so no actions to them can be `seen`.

Since you didn't post a lot of code, I put together this working sample, that shows putting the button outside of `#drag-overlay` and absolutely positioning it with a higher z-index than `#drag-overlay`.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("click");
});
```

```css
#drag-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>TEST</button>
<div id="drag-overlay">
  <div id="drag-overlay-text">This is shown while drag is active...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That’s the question, is this only solvable by putting the buttons/click consumables on a higher z-index?

Comment: @DanielStephens, looking at it from another way, you have a piece of glass sitting above your buttons in a 3D space. Sure, you can see through the glass to see the buttons, but that is an object still blocking your access to those buttons.

Comment: But that just counts only for real objects. CSS is virtual and probably? has something on board to address this, just curious

Comment: @DanielStephens that was an analogy to understand why your element that took 100% of the screen and was placed at the highest point (z-index) was blocking the interaction with all of the elements below it. Think of Z-index as layering, if you have an element at the top most layer, nothing below it is accessible.

Comment: Oh, I absolutely understand! But as mentioned, I really thought there would be a workaround for this. Technically I don't see a reason for a layer letting through click events, while drag events are handled by the "registered" drag event handler